# Quick Question About Fetch And NSObject

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, fetch

I have the following code that fetches a `Session` object for a particular `Exercise` object.

This fetch loads data into my UITableView.

The count is fine, I just need a way to extract the Session.timeStamp property so I can set it to UITableViewCell's textLabel property.

Does anyone know how?

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", exercise.name]];
NSEntityDescription *sessionEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:sessionEntity];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
NSMutableArray *mutableSessionArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (Exercise *ex in results) {
    Session *session = [ex exercises];
    [mutableSessionArray addObject:session];
    }
self.sessionArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableSessionArray];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call timestamp property of your mananged object subclass or call valueForKey.

Comment: how exactly? I've tried `sesssion.timeStamp` but it does not recognize it.

Comment: you have to look at the Session.h to see what dynamic properties are defined. It is possible that you don't have a current version showing all properties you have defined in the data model. Then you need to delete and recreate the Session.h.

Comment: The Session.h file is fine.  In the parent view, I use the Session.timeStamp property just fine.  Perhaps I need to make a Session iVariable for this class and set it from the object at index path from the sessionARray?

Comment: you are probably not really getting a Session object from your fetch